# Does a lightsaber have a cauterizing effect when cutting off appendages, or not?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

The reason I ask this question is because in A New Hope.. there is a scene when Kenobi cuts off Ponda Baba's arm, and we can see that it is bloody on the ground. However, if we go back to the newer (older) movies, there is a scene where Mace Windu snags the head off of Jango Fett. It appears as though it is cauterized by the heat and burning of the lightsaber itself. Also in numerous video games, such as the Jedi Knight series, dismemberment from lightsabers yields no blood and appears to automatically cauterize the wound. Any thoughts?

Edit - Almost forgot about the scene when Luke gets his hand snagged off - There is no blood!

Comment: Possibly not a dupe, but very much related: [Would a lightsaber melt or vaporize a bullet?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30497/would-a-lightsaber-melt-or-vaporize-a-bullet).

Comment: I believe it's mentioned in the EU that it does generally cauterize the wound.

Comment: The OOU explanation is that in A New Hope, they hadn't really decided how lightsabers worked yet, ie, it wasn't decided that they cut by burning/melting. Note that Ben Kenobi's cloak isn't burnt when Vader's lightsaber slices through it either.

Comment: I'd say the reason for no blood in the video game, is so the people don't freak out about violence in video games.  Seems like several games have been de-blooded so the game rating is lower

Comment: in before Ponda Baba is actually terribly unlucky and is a member of the only race in existance that bleeds after being cut with a lightsaber

Comment: Hmmm... blood when Luke cut off the ice beast's arm on Hoth, I seem to remember?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The lightsaber is supposed to instantly cauterize the wound... from posts on

http://www.killermovies.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-356672-where-is-the-blood-in-star-wars.html

A lot of people are claiming it is simply a mistake in the first movies.

But in the Star Wars Wikia it states...

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsaber

> A lightsaber blade was a mass-less form that neither radiated heat nor
>   expended energy until it came into contact with something solid. The
>   power of the energy blade was so great that it could cut through
>   almost anything, although the speed through which it cut depended on
>   the density of the subject. One important note about lightsaber wounds
>   is that they rarely bled profusely, even when a limb had been severed.
>   This is because the energy blade cauterized the wound as it passed,
>   and thus even a severe wound did not tend to bleed heavily.

This means you may still bleed but not a lot from the lightsaber wound.

Edit: Also want to state I looked up more about cauterization...

According to this website

http://www.stuffyoushouldknow.com/blog/stuff-knows-guide-proper-adulthood-cauterize-wound/

When cauterizing a wound with fire... It states..

> Next, get a stick or something else to bite down on because you’re
>   going to need it. If you have alcohol, pour it on the wound to clean
>   it as best you can. Now comes the moment you’ve been dreading, but
>   it’s a move that could save your life. Gently press the hot metal onto
>   the wound, holding it long enough to seal it, but not so long that
>   you’re burning into your healthy body tissue. Try applying it in short
>   bursts so you don’t overdo it, checking the bleeding as you go. When
>   you don’t see any blood flowing, it means you’ve done a bang up job.

From this we can gather that cauterizing a wound sometimes takes a couple of tries... Even though a lightsaber may cauterize stuff instantly, perhaps it doesn't "always" stop 100% of the bleeding.

Comment: Wikia is frequently just what some guy wrote to explain what they see in a movie. Unless that statement has references to canon sources, it should not be taken TOO seriously as proof.

Comment: All of the wikia has many different sources... They usually link every really important facts to one of the sources at the bottom...  And it's widely known that lightsabers use a "frozen laser beam"... Lasers are used to cauterize wounds... So it's not a giant leap to think that lightsabers could instantly cauterize a wound... Now the only problem is determining if this is the case if one person would bleed a little..

Or did you not bother to look all the way at the bottom for the sources?

Comment: I'm not saying that the Wikia is *wrong*, just that, absent a cite, it is not guaranteed to be right and can't be used as source of authoritiative info (whenever my answers quote Wikia that's uncited I try to clearly STATE the lack of cite)

Comment: It's clearly shown that every almost every single depiction of a lightsaber wound there's cauterization it can be easily inferred that bleeding rarely occurs.

Comment: Yep. That's what I mean. It's better if the answer shows the screenshot, or quotes a novel. OR cites Wiki piece doing that.

Comment: The fact that bleeding rarely occurs shows that the quote is then valid...  Because you cannot prove otherwise...  And since we have one depiction of a person bleeding from it (not sure if George Lucas ever really did say it was a mistake) then it's true.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12540/discussion-between-dvk-and-doctorwho22)

Comment: If you look at my second comment, I explicitly stated "I'm **not saying** that the Wikia is wrong" :)

Comment: In *A New Hope*, the severed limb is shown on the ground with a relatively small amount of liquid.  It's not unreasonable to think that the wound was cauterized, yet perhaps the burnt crust cracked open on impact with the floor and some blood leaked out.  Ewww.

Comment: That second quote... OUCH.

Comment: That first quote is obviously wrong, though. At least according to EU/Legends, a lightsaber blade is a tube of plasma, which may be lightweight but is not massless. Also, a lightsaber blade not in contact with anything solid both *glows* and *hums*, so it must expend energy.

Comment: It's funny because somebody actually did an article stating the the science behind it shows that the lightsaber doesn't expend energy until the energy loop is broken. "Lightsabers are power guzzlers- or they were. Modern lightsabers contain a superconductor inside the hilt, which returns looped energy from the negative-charged flux aperture back into the internal power cell. Because of this, the lightsaber only expends energy when that energy loop is broken, such as when it’s cutting something."  https://sciencedaydreams.wordpress.com/tag/lightsaber/

Answer (score 10):

I think the difference is Ponda Baba had non-human physiology. His arm appears to be resemble a blood-filled tube (i.e., a huge combined vein/artery in the middle of it). As such, it couldn't be expected to cauterize as efficiently as human arm when cut off by lightsaber.

Comment: This is actually a pretty good point.  How this race's physiology works doesn't tell us anything about others (in particular humans)

Answer (score 1):

First let me start by saying this is something I've discussed with quite a few fans in my personal quest for an answer.

To the first point: Everything I understand about the lightsaber would lead me to believe it would cauterize the wound upon passing through, but I don't think you could cauterize a knife wound with a lightsaber. I've never used heat to cauterize a wound so I cannot attest to that specific post, but what I've learned in the military tells me that post is correct. should happen fairly quickly, but it may take a second press.

So in the Star Wars universe I know of only one other time a lightsaber produces blood, and its from a humanoid. When Obi-wan slices Darth Maul in two, a spray of blood a la Kill Bill can be seen, if only quite briefly.  Since we see a few seconds later that he is indeed cut clean in half, we cant assume he only partially cut the body leaving a segment to rip or still be connected etc etc. As far as Ponda bleeding, I'm gonna side with the previous comments there. His physiology is likely not like ours with tiny veins carrying blood, but possibly more like a spider whose limbs are simply liquid filled cavities with organs kinda floating in it.

Other than that, its all speculation on an alternate universe, so the answer could simply be, "Because Star Wars."

Answer (score 0):

It has been confirmed that Ponda Boba's species have the same blood system as a spider in current canon. The wound wouldn't cauterize as efficiently. Darth Maul is a zabrak who have more resilient skin. The tissue is too tough to cauterize instantly.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! This looks like a promising answer but you need to cite sources so others can verify your claims. Please take a look at the [help] to learn how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes

**Lightsabers have occasionally *explicitly* been  described as having a cauterizing effect.** For example, when Anakin beheads Dooku, the novelization describes the wound as "cauterized" (of course, the movie supports this, since we don’t see any fountain of blood):

> The severed head’s stare was fixed on something beyond living sight.
> The desperate plea frozen in place on its lips echoed silence. The
> headless torso collapsed with a slowly fading sigh from the cauterized
> gape of its trachea, folding forward at the waist as though making
> obeisance before the power that had ripped away its life.
>
> <sub>*Revenge of the Sith* (novelization)</sub>

**Even when the word “cauterized” is not used, the films *generally* show things this way, as well as not showing any blood**.

Anakin’s legs glowing after Obi-Wan amputates them:

[image]

**The books also almost invariably show severed body parts as exhibiting some degree of burning** (if it’s mentioned at all).

> He was looking at a hand. The hand had brown skin. The hand held a
> lightsaber. The hand had a charred oval of tissue where it should have
> been attached to an arm.
>
> <sub>*Revenge of the Sith (novelization)*</sub>

And wounds are often **explicitly described as having no blood**:

> “This is what happens to those who would resist the Empire,” the gray
> creature said.
>
> He threw his still-spinning lightsaber at Kolvin and sliced him in
> half. Kaeden screamed, expecting fountains of blood, but both halves
> of the body thudded cleanly to the ground and did not so much as
> twitch.
>
> <sub>*Ahsoka*</sub>

It’s perhaps worth noting that the new novelization of *A New Hope* describes Ponda’s arm as "sizzling" after being cut off,  so there’s definitely still heat at work:

> Han could have sworn the severed arm—not to mention the creature’s
> remaining stump—was still sizzling when the old fossil calmly switched
> his blue laser sword off.
>
> <sub>*The Princess, the Scoundrel, and the Farm Boy*</sub>

On the other hand, it’s difficult to argue with the film. Even in new and improved versions of *A New Hope*, the arm is definitely bleeding.

[image]

So Ponda’s arm definitely was not cauterized. **As to *why*, there are lots of potential explanations, though I’m not aware of any canon one (yet).** Most likely, Aqualish have a bizarre physiology, which means that their blood doesn’t boil or coagulate until temperatures are much higher than for humans (or at all).  Weirder things have been seen in Star Wars.